# How to cat and read white spaces from file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file named "rules.txt", this file contains the following below:

```
Jones 2     IP1   1P2
```

The thing now is that "Jones 2" is supposed to be one word. How do I get my script to understand this?

All lines of the file are consistent. I basically have NAT rule names, start ip address and end ip address. The NAT rule names are separated by spaces and there is a tab between the IP addresses.

I don't want to do any splitting. I just want to read the "Jones 2" and also read IP1 and IP2 as 3 separate things in my while loop.

Comment: Is it consistent, that the first two (space separated) fields should be treated as one? Is there always exactly two more fields? Are all of the separators space, or are some tab?

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you expect should happen. Do you want to split each line of the file on sequences of 2 or more spaces (trival with `awk -F' {2,}'`)? What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes this consistent in the file I am using. I basically have NAT rule names, start ip address and end ip address. The NAT rule names are separated by spaces and there is a tab between the IP addresses.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I don't want to do any splitting. I just want to read the "Jones 2" and also read IP1 and IP2 as 3 separate things in my while loop.

Comment: If fields IP1 and IP2 are separated by tabs, then a simple `cut -f1` will return `Jones 2`, and more over `cut -f2` will return IP1 and `cut -f3' will return IP2

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou this works. I am having issues wrapping this method in a loop. Any thoughts?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/   */;/;s/\t/;/' file`

Comment: Using `cut -f1 file` will return first field from eachline of your file. Using something like `IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(cut -f1 <<<$a) )` or using `mapfile`, will create an array with first fields of each line in your file that you can further access using `arr[0]` , `arr[1]` , and so on....  So what you need to do with a loop?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I am basically running an API command to apply each line of the file (Rules & IPs). Initially I wanted to wrap that using a while loop. `cat file.txt | while read name ip1 ip2; do done`

Comment: `while IFS=$'\t' read -r name ip1 ip2;do echo "$name";done <file1`

Answer (score 0):

You could start with

```
perl -pe 's/,/./g;s/  +/,/g' rules.txt
```

then delimit by comma.
Both this in the comment with `awk` use regular expressions which are the popular tool set for manipulating text.

`(  +)` is a synonym for `( {2,})` both meaning "two or more spaces".
The "+" is preceded by two spaces but stackexchange inline code blocks do not respect white spaces...